# Network Error in bitbucket-hook in Jenkins Integration

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, webhooks

I am using Jenkins version 2.303.1. I am following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTPsnR17MIM&t=939s to integrate my private bitbucket repository to Jenkins (run in Windows). I have set the webhook url in Bitbucket according to the format http://{my IP address}:8080/bitbucket-hook/ and also forwarded the request in my WiFi-LAN admin site according to the tutorial. I also added URL in Override Repository URL option in the project configuration setting in bitbucket. I have put the account name and password of my account in the credentials part of repository description.

[Screenshot of project config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0jom.png)

But whenever I push any change in my repository from my local machine, the webhook log history always shows **Network Error**. What is the possible solution to this problem?

Note: I have also tried without the credentials but still faced the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You cant expose localhost to internet so use need to use ngrok or cloudflared tunnel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).